# Failed unit test cases after nodejs update

Tags: unit-testing, phantomjs, angular-cli

After NodeJS update, unit test cases are failing. Earlier the unit test cases were running fine. Below is the error. I am using gulp, karma to run the test cases. Running on macOS high Sierra

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR   {
>       "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'\nReferenceError: Can't find variable:
>   xxxModule\nReferenceError: Can't find variable:
>   xxxModule\nReferenceError: Can't find variable: xxxModule",
>       "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'\nReferenceError: Can't find variable:
>   xxxModule\nReferenceError: Can't find variable:
>   xxxModule\nReferenceError: Can't find variable: xxxModule"   }

Comment: Um, could you provide a bit more detail? Current and previous versions of the CLI? Operating system? Brief description of the app and the kinds of tests you have?